# LibGDX - getting correct extra matrixes and attributes for GLSL Shaders

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader

I want to know how to get correct `Model-View`, `View`, `Normal` matrixes and also extra attributes such as `Tangent` and `Binormal` using `LibGDX` for my shader?

Now I get these parameters like below:

**Model-View matrix:**

```
modelViewMatrix.set(camera.view);       
modelViewMatrix.mul(renderable.worldTransform);
program.setUniformMatrix(u_matModelView, modelViewMatrix);
```

**View matrix (EyeView):**

```
program.setUniformMatrix(u_matView, camera.view);
```

**Normal matrix:**

```
viewInvTraMatrix.set(camera.view);      
viewInvTraMatrix.mul(renderable.worldTransform); //multiply to world transformation matrix
program.setUniformMatrix(u_matModelView, viewInvTraMatrix);
viewInvTraMatrix.inv(); //inverse
viewInvTraMatrix.tra(); //transpose
program.setUniformMatrix(u_matViewInverseTranspose, viewInvTraMatrix);

//IN VERTEX SHADER:
mat3 normalMatrix = mat3(u_matViewInverseTranspose);
```

As far as I know `LibGDX` team added `a_tangent` attribute. So I get it from shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_tangent;
```

And seems to me it works. I can't say the same about `a_binormal` attribute. But this is not problem, because I obtain it from formula in vertex shader:

```
 vec3 n = normalize(normalMatrix * a_normal);     
 vec3 t = normalize(normalMatrix * a_tangent);
 vec3 binormal = cross (n, t);
```

So I need to know is it correct? If yes, why doesn't simple `normal mapping` shader work (see my question: [Normal mapping GLSL using LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825918/normal-mapping-glsl-using-libgdx))? If not, how to get correct parameters? Thank you in advance!